# Is there symmetrize option for texture image?

Tags: texturing, uv

There is a function to symmetrize mesh "mesh>symmetrize"(+x to -x etc.) in Blender, but is there a function like this for texture?

Now, I have a symmetric mesh and an asymmetric texture, and I want symmetrize this texture to match mesh.

Comment: I don’t think so, but you can do it in an external editor like GIMP, or depending on the scenario use mirrored UVs to get symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to symmetrize a Texture, because it would be a waste of 50% or more of the space. If no triangle goes across the line of symmetry, you could just select half of the UV map and scale by X = -1. Otherwise you can symmetrize inside your material either by only using half of the image texture, or by scaling on a chosen axis by 2 (for single-axis symmetry this will cause a distortion):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I'm sorry for poor information. I'm now woking on 3D anime character face, and there are both symmetric and asymmetric parts in a texture. Before I paint asymmetric texture I painted symmetric picture, but because I didn't check symmetric painting button "x", just half of face have texture. Actual situation is a bit more complecated, but like this. Also, because I will inport the model in Unity etc., I want to edit texture directly.